# Is it possible to trigger Supert+W when moving the mouse cursor to the bottom right corner?

Tags: unity, window-manager

I would like to trigger the excellent <kbd>Super</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd> <kbd>W</kbd> window overview when moving the mouse cursor to the bottom right corner. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### [Unity Tweak Tool](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/unity-tweak-tool)

With this tool it is possible to activate windows spread on a hot corner. Go to *Window Manager > Hot Corners*, switch to <kbd>ON</kbd> and select *Spread all Windows* in the dropdown list for the bottom right corner (or any other):

[image]